# how do i copy text by using cmd?

Tags: cmd

I am totally really new to commanding, and I am making a program to type a text and press enter, but I can't find how to type a text by using cmd, so I figured out I can copy the text and paste it and press enter. But I can't find how to copy and paste.

Is there any way to type words in cmd? I want words to be like '~~~ (var)st'for first, '~~~ (var+1)st' next, and '~~~ (var+2)st' by repeating these.

I made this simply in scratch, and link is:
https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/637040443/

Comment: your scratch "program" translated to `cmd`: `for /l %i in (101,1,1000) do @(echo ~~~%ist & ping -n 1 -w 300 localhost >nul)`

Answer (score 0):

To get that type text and enter kind of thing you have to use this bit of code
`set /p VARIABLE_NAME=What is your favorite food? :` 
Notice that I have written the question after an Equal sign
`set /p VARIABLE_NAME=` is important while the rest including the VARIABLE_NAME should be modified
To get the value, type `%VARIABLE_NAME%` (Make sure variable name is the same as in the set command)
Example Program :
`@echo off
set /p name=What is your name? : 
echo %name% is a cool person!!!`
P.S. there should also be a space after the question... Otherwise it will look wierd